# How Firefox finds out download file name on cnet.com?

Tags: download, http-headers, content-disposition

Using `Fiddler` and also `Live HTTP Headers` I tried to find out how Firefox knows what's the name of file and shows it at `Save As dialog`.There's a `Content-Disposition` in headers which has no file name: `Content-Disposition: attachment` which should be `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...`. Then how Firefox knows the file name ?

sample URL:

> http://download.cnet.com/Flock/3000-2356_4-75210908.html?tag=contentMain;contentBody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site redirects to

> `http://software-files-l.cnet.com/s/software/11/57/77/21/FlockSetup_1_2_213_0_3PD.exe?e=1289760172&h=6a553713be5eede3474e961542ad7db8&lop=link&ptype=1901&ontid=2356&siteId=4&edId=3&spi=27176364f3c3621b51584f0aa2c67dc6&pid=11577721&psid=75210908&fileName=FlockSetup_1_2_213_0_3PD.exe`

BThe filename portion of the URL (between the last `/` and the querystring) is `FlockSetup_1_2_213_0_3PD.exe`.

Comment: Is it part of HTTP standard to put file name there and not to set the Content-Disposition header ?

Comment: @Xaqron: A URL contains a path and an optional querystring.  THe end of the path is a filename.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate guess would be from the filename part of the URL of the file you're downloading.

For example: `http://example.com/dir/file.ext` has `file.ext` as filename part.

Comment: I thought about that. But this way Firefox needs a long list of websites and how they handle file names. Also the actual download starts on next redirection, it means Firefox remember it for then the download is starting ?!